# Replace a number in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok so i have the following string,

```
var str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9}';
```

Now i know how to replace specific characters/words like,

```
var newStr = str.replace(/{Foo}/g, 'bar');
```

But how would i replace that {9} when the number can be any number?

Comment: `newstr = str.replace(/{\d+}/g, 'something');`

Comment: [Special characters meaning in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: @anubhava thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the meta sequence for a digit `\d`.

```js
var str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9}',
    newStr = str.replace(/{\d+}/g, 'bar');

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `\{/d+}/g` regex to match any number:

- The `\d` metacharacter matches a digit
- The `+` quantifier means 1 or more of the matched type
- The `/g` modifier means perform a global match

```js
var str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9}';
var newstr = str.replace(/{\d+}/g, 'number');
console.log(newstr);
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {99199} and {435}';
newstr = str.replace(/\d+/g, 'number');
console.log(newstr);
```

By the way, I used [this tool](http://scriptular.com/#%7B%5Cd%2B%7D%7C%7C%7C%7Cg%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22some%20text%20%7BFoo%7D%20some%20more%20text%20%7B9%7D%22%5D) to test my regex, thought this might come in handy if you want to try out more regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what's a “number”, so I devised a solution that works not only for positive integers but also for signed integers and floats and takes care of nested parentheses.

`/{\d+}/g` matches one or more digits within curly brackets

```js
var str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9}';

var m = str.match(/{\d+}/g);
console.log(m); // m = [ "{9}" ]
```

But the above pattern doesn't match floats, e.g. `{3.14}`

```js
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14}';

m = str.match(/{\d+}/g);
console.log(m); // m = [ "{9}" ]
```

And what about double parentheses are they okay?

```js
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14} and {{8}}';
m = str.match(/{\d+}/g);
console.log(m); // m = [ "{9}", "{8}" ]
```

You can use this to match floats

```js
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14} and {{8}}';
m = str.match(/{(\-|\+)?(\d+(\.\d+)?)}/g);
console.log(m); // m = [ "{9}", "{3.14}", "{8}" ]
```

So here's a solution allowing nested curly brackets

```js
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14} and {{8}}';
var newStr = str.replace(/{(\-|\+)?(\d+(\.\d+)?)}/g, '{NUMBER}');
console.log(newStr);
```

**Taking care of nested parentheses**

Match everything between curly brackets and check for numeric values (regular expression is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14} and {{8}}';
m = str.match(/{.+?}/g);
console.log(m); // m = [ "{Foo}", "{9}", "{3.14}", "{{8}" ]
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  mi = m[i];
  value = mi.slice(1, mi.length - 1);
  // regular expression for parsing floats from:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat
  if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)$/
    .test(value)) {
    console.log("matches a number: ", value);
  }
};
```

Write a function to replace numeric values only

```js
function replaceNumber(string, repl) {
  return string.replace(/{.+?}/g, function(match) {
    value = match.slice(1, match.length - 1);
    if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)$/
      .test(value)) {
      return '{' + repl + '}';
    } else {
      return match;
    }
  });
}


str = 'some text {Foo} some more text {9} and {3.14} and {{8}} and {-2}';

newStr = replaceNumber(str, 'NUMBER');
console.log(newStr); 
// newStr = some text {Foo} some more text {NUMBER} and {NUMBER} and {{8}} and {NUMBER}
```